# Adult Fantasy with a protagonist like Arya Stark

Tags: fantasy, agent, dark-fantasy, pitching

I'm pitching an adult fantasy book with a young protagonist much like Arya Stark in temperament and capabilities, and I'm having difficulty setting that expectation with my comps. There are plenty of characters like her, but everything I'm finding is YA.

I don't want to comp A Song of Ice and Fire directly because I understand agents frown upon comping mega-bestseller books. My other choice was Mattie Ross from True Grit, which is now around 60 years old. Do any of you know a recent adult fantasy with a child protagonist who isn't afraid to commit a few murders? Thanks.

Comment: What do *a comp* and *to comp* mean?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a list question.

Comment: @Ben A comparison.  It's a short-hand used to quickly convey the nature of a book -- elevator pitch style.

Comment: This question might be better if it was re-phrased as "how does one identify potential comps in the vast sea of existing media?" -- This question, as written, can **only** ever help OP, but a broader question, with a more generalized answer, could hep OP and many other future users.

Comment: @Ben Comp is short for comparable, or I've heard it 'competitive' title. To comp another book is to suggest that audiences who bought that book will also enjoy yours.

Comment: @codeMonkey I understand. I guess I should have asked Reddit or something. To rephrase it as you suggest would make it no longer useful to me, and honestly, I could have answered that question. Go ahead and close it.

Comment: @IchabodE - I just went ahead and answered it as if you'd made my edit. ;-)

Comment: @IchabodE Please note that comp is shorthand by using the full word followed by a the shorthand in parathesis to denote it's use for the rest of the question.  (I.e compare (comp)).   Please avoid using industry jargon like this as not everyone in the stack works in publishing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Along the Razor's Edge by Rob J. Hayes (might be considered "dark
  YA")
- Seven Blades in Black by Sam Sykes (older protagonist than Arya,    but similar themes)
- The Poppy War by R.F. Kuang (less assassin, more
  general of the army).
- Nevernight by Jay Kristoff (protagonist is 16
  years old and trains as an assassin, but the book is a bit old, from
  2016).
- Red Sister by Mark Lawrence (again, less assassin and more
  "trained warrior" and a bit old, from 2017).

Answer (score 1):

### Use Sub-Genres

This kind of comparison exactly what "genre" is useful for.

So I'd initially focus less on the character than the tone, and what that says about genre.

The "dark and gritty" vibe I get from a child-assassin suggests "grimdark" - a sub-genre within fantasy. Lots of cyberpunk fiction has a similar tone, so that might be a good place to look even though it's sci-fi.

From there you can look to authors - [Glen Cook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glen_Cook_bibliography), [Joe Abercrombie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_Abercrombie), and [Andrzej Sapkowski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Witcher) all come to mind, but if you just plug grimdark and cyberpunk into your favorite search engine you'll find many others.

Look for authors and characters that feel similar based on the descriptions online, and read those books if you haven't.

Eventually you end up with something like "if Sapkowski's Lion Cub of Cintra was written by Joe Abercrombie" or whatever it is you feel like captures your character.

Comment: Thank you. My current comp section says "Mattie Ross from True Grit in a world like Joe Abercrombie's The Blade Itself." I would have loved to comp Black Company, but it is SO old.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what "to comp" means, but I presume you mean "Complement" from the music industry, or to use as a template.

I wouldn't do that. An agent has to reject about 98% of the queries they get, simply because they are overwhelmed by queries and don't have the time to do more than read the first paragraph of most of them.

I strongly, **strongly** recommend that you don't model your character's personality or life story on *any other character*. Agents and Publishers and their employees are extremely well read, and if they suspect your character is not original they will reject you without explanation or any opportunity to argue. They have to filter through thousands of submissions to pick the few dozen worth representing or printing.

Fan fiction is not going to cut it; derivative fiction or characters is not going to make it through that filter.

Your child character is just a sociopath, read up on it. Then give them an interesting personality and approach.

If the sociopath is supposed to be the hero, she needs to be an anti-hero, you must find a reason for the readers to root for her; she needs a moralistic reason for her brutality.

Most sociopathic **heroic** characters, like John Wick, are written without being strictly sociopathic. John Wick has sentimental feelings for his dead wife, and the puppy she gave him to care for after her death from cancer.

His revenge in killing a few hundred people for the senseless intentional killing of his dog, without Wick having a moment of compunction or regret, is definitely sociopathic, but for a legitimate harm.

The same thing goes for James Bond in 007, he kills without compunction or regret but is only killing criminals and henchmen in service of the Greater Good.

I'd strongly suggest you give your character the traits of a sociopath but with a moral stripe. Arya Stark is ruthless in her fearless seeking of vengeance for legitimate wrongs perpetrated against her and her family.

Hm, sounds a lot like John Wick, but both original in their execution -- pun intended! Both are driven by cold rage and vengeance.

That is about the extent of imitation you should be using. Develop an original character with an original origin story, and an original grievous harm, in a world of your own devising.

If you want your character to be the hero of the story, give them a reason. For John Wick it began with Vengeance, and he succeeded, then in sequels it has become about self-preservation, dealing with the consequences of his vengeance, within the organization he tried to leave.

Good luck. Be original. Do not "comp", or crib from other author's characters, *especially* their origin stories. At least five and up to a dozen people that can advise against publication will read your book before it gets published, all professional readers familiar with the publishing market. Any of them might call attention to your cribbing, and it doesn't matter if it technically does not violate copyright, they want to publish *original* work, not knock off derivative stories.

Nobody wants a first critic's review to be "A poor imitation of Arya Stark."

Comment: OP is *pitching* a book (that's probably already written).

Comment: While I thank you for your response, as Ben said, the book is written. My character is no copy of Arya, or Mattie, she is just along the same vein. Comp is short for comparable, or I've heard it 'competitive.' Either way, you are giving the agent a broad-strokes idea of who the audience for your story is based on other books they have loved.

My character is dirt poor and lives with her parents on the border between two kingdoms. She steals from the bodies on a nearby battlefield and finishes off anyone who isn't quite dead. Not Arya.